# Issues running ruby script as cron job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, ruby

I have a ruby script which i want to run as cron job.It runs perfectly fine when i run through command prompt on a linux machine. But when i run that same script using a cron job it fails.

I get following error with string encoding. Not sure why it only complains when i am running as a cron job. I have also set my shell to /bin/bash in crontab, which is same shell as my command prompt.

The error i get is

> in `encode': "\xE2" on US-ASCII (Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError)

the line of code that causes the error is

```
split.encode('utf-8).split(some_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you have set, in the `crontab` environment, US-ASCII as your language, and that in such language the string "\xE2" does not exist. Most likely, this is due to the fact that the string is ASCII-8bit encoded, while you need to convert it to UTF-8.

It is possible that the string was contaminated by some invisible character, as it often happens when you do a cut and paste.

The following, to be applied **before** manipulating the string, should solve your problem:

```
  new_str = some_str.encode('utf-8', 'binary', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '')
```